# ASP.NET Core "This localhost page can’t be found"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

When trying to test my application i get "This localhost page can’t be found" using vs2017.

Trying to reach https://localhost:44347/test/test

This is my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why there is no route template in the `app.UseMVC();`? Also is this when your start your application OR when you trying an navigate to that page?

Comment: @JamesS I didn't change anything about this file so i don't know why there is no route template. And this is when i start my application because i changed the launch url. to test/test instead of api/values which showed ["value1","value2"]

Comment: Could you please show your controller code.

Comment: @DeepakMishra do you mean the ValuesController? 
https://codeshare.io/arAeBK

Comment: I meant [test/test] action.

Comment: @DeepakMishra https://codeshare.io/2BRBqb

Comment: @T.v.A. that is Index view, which you have sent to me, I am looking for a test controller with test action

Comment: @DeepakMishra I'm sorry I don't know which file you mean. I'm new to this so I apologise. The test/test is a folder named test and a .cshtml file named test.cshtml
https://imgur.com/a/Jl1SP0q

Comment: @T.v.A. ok in that cased you would have to add a new controller TestController, which contains an action method Test which `returns View();`

Comment: @DeepakMishra Ok now i think I know which controller you are talking about. 
https://codeshare.io/5NRdlJ

Comment: @T.v.A. Please see if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon the code shared by you, you would need to explicitly provide the routes using attribute routing.

```
public class ProjectenEnPersoneelCONTROLLER : Controller
{
    [Route("Test/Test")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"D:\Users\tijnv\source\repos\API_STA_1\API_STA_1\Json\test-request.json");
        var projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Projects>(json);
        return View(projects);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can rename controller to TestController and Action method to Test

```
public class TestController : Controller
{

    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"D:\Users\tijnv\source\repos\API_STA_1\API_STA_1\Json\test-request.json");
        var projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Projects>(json);
        return View(projects);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does something but it doesn't seem to work. It's looking for Test.cshtml in a folder called Views. https://imgur.com/a/IF6uf2O

Comment: @T.v.A. you can provide the path in view constructor as first parameter and second parameter as model `return View("Views/Home/Index.cshtml", project)`

Comment: Thank you this works! I can now see the test/test but I have a different error, could you help with this? https://imgur.com/a/Ec95e7c

Comment: Try foreach with just Model only, instead of Model.products, you can also check by adding a breakpoint if the property exists and it's IEnumerable.

Comment: When I remove teh .projects I get the error: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Projects' because 'Projects' does not contain a public instance definition of 'GetEnumerator'